# граница прозрачного элемента при DragOver\Enter\Leave winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, border

Доброго всем! До этого с рисованием не работал совсем. А жаль) Есть форма с opacity = 60%. На форму при загрузке динамически добавляется DropTaskPanel (далее контрол), унаследованный от Panel. Он по умолчанию имеет такую же прозрачность. С необходимыми событиями справился, контрол добавляется, все работает - молодца.Но! Есть одна нереализованная фича. Контрол по умолчанию должен иметь границу определенного цвета - допустим красного. При событиях DragOver\Enter = цвет меняется на какой-нибудь другой. Вроде бы все просто, но этот самый контрол должен быть закругленным + чтобы он был юзабилен в будущем отрисовка границы должна быть описана внутри класса DropTaskPanel. В чем проблема? - задать BorderStyle не проблема. 
Проблема в том, что 
1. закругленные углы элемента не имеют границы, если использую CreateRoundRectRgn
2. Пробовал тупо рисовать GraphicsPath - не получилось.

Подскажите что делаю не так. Ниже листинг DropTaskPanel без вышеописанного

```
using System;
```

using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CCLib.Properties;
using MLib;
using ContentAlignment = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment;
using IDataObject = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject;

namespace CCLib
{
    public class DropTaskPanel : Panel
    {
        public event Action Dropped;

```
    private Label DragD { get; set; }
    private Label Or { get; set; }
    private LinkLabel Browse { get; set; }
    private PictureBox Icon { get; set; }

    public Color  BorderColor { get; set; } = Color.Gray;
    public int Corner { get; set; } = 20;

    public DropTaskPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DragD.DragEnter += DragD_DragEnter;
        DragD.DragOver += DragD_DragOver;
        DragD.DragDrop += DragD_DragDrop;

        Or.DragEnter += Or_DragEnter;
        Or.DragOver += Or_DragOver;
        Or.DragDrop += Or_DragDrop;

        Browse.DragEnter += Browse_DragEnter;
        Browse.DragOver += Browse_DragOver;
        Browse.DragDrop += Browse_DragDrop;

        Icon.DragEnter += Icon_DragEnter;
        Icon.DragOver += Icon_DragOver;
        Icon.DragDrop += Icon_DragDrop;
    }
    ~DropTaskPanel()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        Width = 340;
        Height = 112;
        AllowDrop = true;
        ForeColor = Color.Lime;
        AllowDrop = true;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        DragD = new Label
        {
            Location = new Point(100, 5),
            ForeColor = Color.Lime,
            AutoSize = true,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
            AllowDrop = true
        };
        Or = new Label
        {
            Location = new Point(90, 90),
            ForeColor = Color.Lime,
            AutoSize = true,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
            AllowDrop = true
        };

        //TODO location if English

        Browse = new LinkLabel
        {
            Location = new Point(115, 90),
            ForeColor = Color.Lime,
            LinkColor = Color.Lime,
            ActiveLinkColor = Color.Green,
            LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.HoverUnderline,
            AutoSize = true,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
            AllowDrop = true
        };

        Icon = new PictureBox
        {
            Location = new Point(130, 25),
            BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
            Width = 74,
            Height = 65,
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
            AllowDrop = true,
            Image = Resources.drop
        };

        Controls.Add(DragD);
        Controls.Add(Or);
        Controls.Add(Browse);
        Controls.Add(Icon);
    }

    #region panel drag events
    protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
    { 
        Icon.Image = Resources.drop2;

        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        Point p = Cursor.Position;
        Win32Point wp;
        wp.x = p.X;
        wp.y = p.Y;
        IDropTargetHelper dropHelper = (IDropTargetHelper)new DragDropHelper();
        dropHelper.DragOver(ref wp, (int)e.Effect);
    }
    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        var p = Cursor.Position;
        Win32Point wp;
        wp.x = p.X;
        wp.y = p.Y;
        var dropHelper = (IDropTargetHelper)new DragDropHelper();
        dropHelper.DragEnter(Handle, e.Data as IDataObject, ref wp, (int)e.Effect);
    }
    protected override void OnDragLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        Icon.Image = Resources.drop;
        IDropTargetHelper dropHelper = (IDropTargetHelper)new DragDropHelper();
        dropHelper.DragLeave();
    }

    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Dropped?.Invoke(e);
    }
    #endregion
    #region included controls drag events
    private void Icon_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => OnDragEnter(e);
    private void Icon_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => OnDragOver(e);
    private void Icon_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => OnDragDrop(e);

    private void Browse_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => OnDragEnter(e);
    private void Browse_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => OnDragOver(e);
    private void Browse_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => OnDragDrop(e);

    private void Or_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => OnDragEnter(e);
    private void Or_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => OnDragOver(e);
    private void Or_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => OnDragDrop(e);

    private void DragD_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => OnDragEnter(e);
    private void DragD_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => OnDragOver(e);
    private void DragD_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => OnDragDrop(e);
    #endregion

    public void SetLanguage(Language language)
    {
        if (language == Language.English)
        {
            Browse.Text = Resources.DropTaskPanel_SetLanguage_browse;
            Or.Text = Resources.DropTaskPanel_SetLanguage_or;
            DragD.Text = Resources.DropTaskPanel_SetLanguage_drag_files_here;
        }
        else
        {
            Browse.Text = Resources.DropTaskPanel_SetLanguage_Browse_rus;
            Or.Text = Resources.DropTaskPanel_SetLanguage_Or_rus;
            DragD.Text = Resources.DropTaskPanel_SetLanguage_DragHere_rus;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Недоработку с морганием PictureBox'а не учитывать - с этим справлюсь, это не так приоритетно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача решается и просто и сложно одновременно.

1. Сначала сложности: Если вы хотите реализовать контрол произвольной формы (хоть в дырочку, хоть в форме буквы, если выдерните векторные глифы из шрифтов), то вам придется взять на себя всю отрисовку вашего контрола. Всю от слова совсем: и рамочки и эффекты при выделении и все остальное. Стандартные границы и стили использовать не получится, т.к. они жестко завязаны на WinAPI и изменить их форму нельзя, во всяком случае я не нашел вариантов это сделать даже через прямые вызовы WinAPI функций.
   Если вас не пугает этот факт переходим к следующему шагу.
2. Задаем форму внешней границы контрола с помощью `GraphicsPath` и кладем ее в свойство `Control.Region`. Все. С этого момента активная область (область реагирующая на события), а также видимая область (все что отрисовывается) вашего контрола определяется заданной нами границей. Форма границы может быть абсолютно любой.

Для проверки, можете взять контрол с известным поведением, например кнопку и поиграть со свойством `Control.Region`. Прием опробован на практике, работал вроде бы без замечаний, если найдете баги, обязательно поделитесь =)

Comment: спасибо, попробую и отпишусь

Comment: долго сюда не заходил. Спасибо за совет - все получилось, а picturebox'ы и label'ы (чтобы не моргали и чтобы не писать лишний код) убрал, заменив их отрисовкой